# Electron - send a custom event from Menu to renderer

Tags: javascript, menu, electron, keyboard-shortcuts

*I stumbled across a problem that I had a lot of problem finding documentation for while creating an Electron app. This is a Question / Answer on how to have a custom Electron menu item communicate with the application frontend.*

*Please let me know if this kind of post is useful or if some parts need to be elaborated.*

---

For one of my apps I wanted my frontend to display pictures inside a directory. When the user clicks on his **right arrow key** I want to go to the next picture. I wanted this behavior to be handled by the inbuilt ***Electron Menu Accelerator***.

I have built my app separating my `main.js` from my menu templates like so:

```sh
app
├── main.js
├── renderer.js
├── index.html
├── templates
        ├── menu.js => uses objects from picture.js and about.js to build & return a menu
        ├── picture.js
        ├── about.js
├── ... (rest of files)
```

My picture.js looked something like this:

```js
const picture = {
    label: 'Picture',
    role: 'help',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Previous',
        accelerator: 'Left',
        click: function() {
            // this needs to be figured out
        },
      },
      {
        label: 'Next',
        accelerator: 'Right',
        click: function() {
            // this needs to be figured out
        },
      }
    ],
}

exports.picture = picture;
```

My gut-feeling told me to fiddle around with [ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main), but this approach just didn't work. I got a lot of messages saying that `ipc is not defined` or that `the method send of undefined` would not work.

Here is how I managed to solve my problem:

Answer (score 2):

**What we know:** For communication between the Menu and the frontend, we need to create an event in `main.js`. And it is `main.js` that will send an event to `renderer.js`.

**What we found while searching:** It is possible to send messages from the main process to the renderer process using [webContents.send](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args)

**How to apply it:** We need 'app' (the application object) to be called and 'emit' an event. This is why we had to change the 'picture' object to being a function taking one argument: app.

```js
const fileMenu = () => {
  return {
    label: 'Picture',
    role: 'help',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Previous',
        accelerator: 'Left',
        click: () => app.emit('prevPicture'),
      },
      {
        label: 'Next',
        accelerator: 'Right',
        click: () => app.emit('nextPicture'),
      }
    ],
  }
}

exports.fileMenu = fileMenu;
```

And then we just need to add the argument in main:

```js
// LOTS OF CODE ...
// mainWindow is the name of the Electron BrowserWindow object that holds our menu and app

app.on('ready', function() {
  const template = new AppMenu([fileMenu(app), editMenu, windowMenu, aboutMenu]).getTemplate();
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
  createWindow();
});

// OTHER CODE ...
app.on('prevPicture', () => {mainWindow.webContents.send('prevPicture');});
app.on('nextPicture', () => {mainWindow.webContents.send('nextPicture');});

// REST OF CODE ...
```

This allows us to use a simple `ipc.on('prevPicture', () => doWhatever)` in our `renderer.js` file and create custom keyboard shortcuts that will affect the frontend in Electron.